# Can't seem to add text to scene in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to three.js and im trying to make some basic code work. However I get this error everytime. I thought I was adding it to the scene after using loader.load so I'm confused why this is happening.

- "three.js:5348 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D."

JS -

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // add the renderer to html


camera.position.z = 6;

const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load('font/UniversalSans-450_Regular.json', function (font) {
   // TextGeometry(String, Object)
   const textObj = new THREE.TextGeometry('Im trying', {
      font: font,
      size: 80,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 10,
      bevelSize: 8,
      bevelOffset: 0,
      bevelSegments: 5
   });
   scene.add(textObj);
});


function animate() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

animate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems:

1. you don't add `Geometry` like `TextGeometry` to a `Scene`. You add things like `Mesh` which take a `Geometry` and a `Material` to `Scene`
2. The camera being 6 units away from text that is 80 units tall means you basically won't see anything. Moved the camera 900 units away

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); // add the renderer to html


camera.position.z = 900;

const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function (font) {
   // TextGeometry(String, Object)
   const textObj = new THREE.TextGeometry('Im trying', {
      font: font,
      size: 80,
      height: 5,
      curveSegments: 12,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 10,
      bevelSize: 8,
      bevelOffset: 0,
      bevelSegments: 5
   });
   const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'});
   const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textObj, material);
   scene.add(mesh);
   console.log('foo');
});


function animate() {
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

animate();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

You might find [these articles](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-fundamentals.html) helpful.

Comment: thank you this was right, I confused but this makes perfect sense

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're setting up your **scene** object.

Did you just not include that part?  Otherwise try pasting this at the top:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

Comment: i accidentally deleted the first line in the question's code oops